# SEO: Moving articles from one domain to another

Tags: seo, search-engines, content, duplicate-content

Currently I have articles up on a website (site A) that is not mine (but I can remove the articles.) The article's aren't faring well (not only due to the recent Google changes) but because they really could do better if I made some tweaks myself instead of relying on the domain owner's SEO skills. So I would like to set up my own website and have just my articles on it (site B.)

In the past when I've moved content, I've set up redirects but this time I can't do that.

What would be the best way to move the articles without having to worry about them being counted as duplicate content or any other lame stuff?

Should I,
A: Save the articles on my computer and remove them from Site A. Wait for Google to remove them from the index (several months.)

B: Remove the articles from Site A and immediately place them on Site B.

Comment: Do you have any access to the server of site A?

Comment: No, I don't have any access to the server on site A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be a solution that you like, but one option would be to spin the articles so that they don't count as duplicate content but say the same thing. If you can change 70 - 80% of the wording you should be fine and change the structure a bit (add paragraph break or something like that)

Then you can post the new version on your site and then include a link on the old version to the new site. This would jumpstart your backlinks to the new site. It wouldn't give you any link juice that the old articles have, but if they are not doing well anyway, that may not matter. If you can't redirect, this is an SEO friendly option.

Also, another thing to keep in mind is that if you are going to be adding more content to the new site quickly, having a couple duplicate articles shouldn't hurt. If there are only a few articles to start with and you will be adding a lot more, Google should see the new content as over powering the old. But this might not be your situation.

Comment: If I remove the content from site A, which I will do in either event... will the duplicate content thing be forever or temporary (just until Google purges my articles from site A from their index?)

Comment: It won't be forever if the old content is removed. It just might take a bit for Google to reindex both the old site and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You say you cannot do redirects. A 301 redirect in the domain company would be the best, (so, having the domain apart from the hosting would have been best here) as you would pass the seo juice to the new location. You say you can't do that, so I guess the old hosting holds the domain too.

If you can "remove" them, but have no access to site A, can you set up on each article title entry (seems that at least you have control over a toc, or summary of articles? (because you can remove them somehow)) a php redirect or something ? So it does not give a 404, but redirects to each new location. (so, no harm done in seo)

Comment: All I can do is add articles to the site and delete them. Something like ehow, hubpages, squidoo. I can't do any redirects or anything like that.

Comment: At squidoo (a user can always there edit content, I don't understand) you can insert html, if I remember well... So maybe is allowed (I don't know) replace content with "This article has been moved here" even plain html thing... (or better a href to the article name, for better seo) If that is not possible, and no other option, yep, then I would just upload the new ones first, then delete from the other site, so to have the less risk possible of duplicated content down ranking. I would very much try first embedding some html or php, I do know from Squidoo, but not the other sites you mention.

Comment: Remember though, that 404 pages, broken links, etc, do harm seo quite. I'd really dig other (301 being surely the best) posibilities. Even considering more than just "touched up" versions, but more solidly changed ones of the same articles, if you opt for leaving "duplicated content".